# How to delete specific words from a list?

Tags: python

I have to different lists of words, one list (stopwords) contains a list of words that should be excluded from the other list (kafka).

I tried:

```
kafka.discard (stop) # this only works with sets and I do not want to transform my list into a set
```

is there another way to exclude the words in stop from the other list?

I am using python 3.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you don't want to work with sets (why?), you can use a list comprehension:

```
kafka[:] = [x for x in kafka if x not in stop]
```

*edit:*  note the `slice[:]`, this method more closely resembles the behaviour of `.discard()` in that the identity of your collection is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
stopwords_set = set(stopwords)

kafka = [word for word in kafka if word not in stopwords_set]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove every word in your `stopwords` list from `kafka` is:

```
for word in stopwords:
    while word in kafka:
        kafka.remove(word)
```

Comment: I believe this will only remove ONE copy of word in kafka rather than all of it.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't account for duplicates.  This is easily fixed by changing `if` to `while`, so I'm not sure this deserves downvotes.  What this solution does that the others don't is allow mutation-in-place, which sounded like it's what the OP was looking for.